# Bounty share not working by the rules

Tags: discussion, bug, bounties

I ask this question because I feel that either the description of the bounty is not clear enough, or that there is a "bug" in the automatic award process.

I see a question which had a bounty of +50 on Stack Overflow. ([Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154455/update-automation-in-sql-server/12154692#12154692))

First the question had two answers. Mine was accepted, but the OP started a bounty and unaccepted the answer. However he wrote a comment what he needs more.

I changed my answer and it was accepted once again. (Just as it is the accepted answer now)
The answer got 3 more upvotes during the bounty period.

However, another user contributed an answer during the bounty period, after an answer was already accepted. He also received 3 upvotes during the bounty period.

It ended with a "community share" +25 for the third answer. I guess because it happened after the bounty started.

What is not clear to me is the following:

The reference from the description:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at
>   least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no
>   answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question
>   owner accepts an answer during the bounty period, and the bounty
>   expires without an explicit award – we assume the bounty owner liked
>   the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the
>   time of bounty expiration.

**My question:**

Since both cases seem to apply, why is the first one stronger (Accepted answer OR Community)? (Is this how it's supposed to work?)

I think that in any case it should be stated somewhere that there is an order in the rules.

Comment: Your answer was already accepted when the bounty started? If yes, that might trigger the first behavior.

Comment: No, before the bounty the OP made a redo on it.

Comment: [According to the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12154455/timeline) the other answer was accepted, unaccepted, and then your answer was accepted and then the bounty expired. Not sure if that's intended behavior (I mean, rewarding to the other answer).

Comment: It seems the OP changed the accepted answer in a few times (like 5 times) but even not the other one (which one was accepted before the bounty too) with 5 upvote got the bounty, but the new (last) answer, which was not accepted.

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby , do you have idea what to do now? Since no answer on my question, and I don't even know it is a bug or what, and how to handle it in the meta. Could you help?

Comment: Ooopsss...glad you asked, it is awkward that none of us received the bounty. I think it has something to do with the fact that the OP accepted/unaceppted several times our answers.

Comment: I just reported it, because it is for sure not clear, how is it working. And may need to change the description. But now no answers and I really don't know what to do. May I should start a bounty on the bug of bounty :)